# Infinite intersection of compact sets empty implies a finite intersection is also empty

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $K_1, K_2,\ldots$ be compact sets in a topological space such that $\cap_i K_i = \emptyset$. I want to show that $\cap_i^m K_i = \emptyset$ for some $m$.

But I am struggling to see why because the topological space itself say we call it $X$ need not be compact itself hence we cannot obtain the finite cover of open sets we need. Because we easily see that if we assume the given we get 
$$\left(\cap_i K_i \right)^c = X \iff \cup_i K_i^c = X,$$
hence we have found an open cover of $X$ but we cannot take a finite amount of $K_i$ such that it still holds as $X$ may not be compact. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need Hausdorffness on the whole space or $K_n = \{n, n+1, n+2 ,\ldots\}$ on the cofinite topology on $\mathbb N$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma you should post your comment as an answer, as it stands the proposition by OP the correct answer is your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Let $L_i = \bigcap_{j=1}^i K_j$, then the $K_1 \setminus L_i$ form an open cover of $K_1$. Now use $K_1$'s compactness to find an $i$ such that $K_1 = K_1 \setminus L_i$ (note that the $K_1 \setminus L_i$ are an increasing sequence), hence $L_i = \emptyset$.

Comment: One maybe dumb question, how is it obvious that all the $K_1 \backslash L_i$ are open? Morgan's law?

Comment: The $L_i$ are compact, hence closed in $K_1$. So their (relative) complements are open (in $K_1$ - they need not to be open in $X$).

Comment: right! thanks alot!