# If $\bigcap\limits_\alpha K_\alpha=\emptyset,$ then there exists $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that $\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n K_{\alpha_k}=\emptyset$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness, alternative-proof

Let $\{K_\alpha\}$ be a collection of compact sets of a Hausdorff space. If  $\displaystyle\bigcap_\alpha K_\alpha=\emptyset,$ then there exists $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that  $\displaystyle\bigcap_{k=1}^n K_{\alpha_k}=\emptyset.$

There is a hint by [martini](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436349/infinite-intersection-of-compact-sets-empty-implies-a-finite-intersection-is-als)

**Hint**. Let $L_i = \bigcap_{j=1}^i K_j$, then the $K_1 \setminus L_i$ form an open cover of $K_1$. Now use $K_1$'s compactness to find an $i$ such that $K_1 = K_1 \setminus L_i$ (note that the $K_1 \setminus L_i$ are an increasing sequence), hence $L_i = \emptyset$.

I don't understand this

> Now use $K_1$'s compactness to find an $i$ such that $K_1 = K_1 \setminus L_i$ (note that the $K_1 \setminus L_i$ are an increasing sequence), hence $L_i = \emptyset$.

why are $L_i$ increasing?

and why

hence $L_i = \emptyset$?

At the moment I have

I have $K_1\cap L_i^c=(K_1\cap K_1^c)\cup\dots\cup(K_1\cap K_j^c)$, all are open in $K_1$ then they cover $K_1,$ $\displaystyle K_1=\bigcup_{j=1}^i K_j^c=\big(\bigcap_{j=1}^i K_j\big)^c$

Could someone help to understand please?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

martini's hint does not help you. It is only applies to the case that you have a countable cover $\{ K_i \}$. Nevertless, the sequence $K_1 \setminus L_i$ is increasing because the sequence $L_i$ is obviously decreasing. Now $\{ K_1 \setminus L_i \}$ is a cover of $K_1$, hence it has a finite subcover. This means (because the sequence $K_1 \setminus L_i$ is increasing ) that there exists $i$ such that $K_1 = K_1 \setminus L_i$. Since each $L_i \subset K_1$, we conclude that $L_i = \emptyset$.

So what can be done in the general situation? Pick any $K_{\alpha_0}$. Then the family $L_\alpha = K_{\alpha_0} \setminus K_\alpha$ is an open cover of $K_{\alpha_0}$. Here we invoke that the compact $K_\alpha$ are closed in the Hausdorff space $X$. Hence there exists a finite subcover $L_{\alpha_1}, \dots, L_{\alpha_n}$ of  $K_{\alpha_0}$. This means $K_{\alpha_0} = \bigcup_{i=1}^n L_{\alpha_i} = K_{\alpha_0} \setminus \bigcap_{i=0}^n K_{\alpha_i}$, in other words $\bigcap_{i=0}^n K_{\alpha_i} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Why can you conclude that $\bigcap_{i=0}^n K_\alpha = \emptyset$ ? Can you explain please?

Comment: Shouldn't this $K_\alpha's$ depend on $i$, like $K_{\alpha_i}$ ?

Comment: I edited my answer. The key is De Morgan's law for the union of complements.

Comment: I think I did it. please correct me if I am wrong. $\bigcup^nL_{\alpha_i}=\bigcup^n(K_{\alpha_0}\setminus K_{\alpha_i})=\bigcup^n(K_{\alpha_0}\bigcap K_{\alpha_i}^c)=(\bigcup^n K_{\alpha_0})\bigcap(\bigcup^n K_{\alpha_i}^c)=K_{\alpha_0}\bigcap(\bigcup^n K_{\alpha_i}^c)=K_{\alpha_0}\bigcap(\bigcap^n K_{\alpha_i})^c=K_{\alpha_0}\setminus\bigcap^n K_{\alpha_i}$

Comment: Thus $K_{\alpha_0}\setminus\emptyset=K_{\alpha_0}\setminus\bigcap^nK_{\alpha_i}$ hence $\bigcap^nK_{\alpha_i}=\emptyset$

Comment: Correct! Note that it is essential that $L_{\alpha_0} = \emptyset$ so that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n L_{\alpha_i} = \bigcup_{i=0}^n L_{\alpha_i}$. Moreover $\bigcap_{i=0}^n K_{\alpha_i}  \subset K_{\alpha_0}$ which allows to conclude $\bigcap_{i=0}^n K_{\alpha_i}  = \emptyset$.

Comment: Is this proof correct too?  $L_\alpha$ is an open cover for $K_{\alpha_0}$.Proof: Let $x\in K_{\alpha_0},$ then we should prove $x\in\bigcup L_\alpha$. Since $L_{\alpha}=K_{\alpha_0}\bigcap(\bigcup K_{\alpha}^c)$ it suffices to prove $x\in\bigcup K_{\alpha}^c$. Suppose it's not true i.e. $x\not\in \bigcup K_{\alpha}^c$, then $x\not\in K_\alpha,$ for all $\alpha\in I$ which is a contradiction since $\alpha_0\in I$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. It is again De Morgan' law: $\bigcup K_\alpha^c = \bigcup (X \setminus K_\alpha) = X \setminus \bigcap K_\alpha = X$.

Comment: ah, it's more direct with your equalities because $x\in X$ in any case. thank you!

Comment: I am with this again, why did you write $\bigcap_{i=0}^n K_{\alpha_i}  \subset K_{\alpha_0}$ in your second comment?

Comment: I think it is clear that $D = \bigcap_{i=0}^n K_{\alpha_i} \subset K_{\alpha_0} = K$ and you want to know why this is important. For a general $D \subset X$, the equation $K \setminus D = K$ implies $K \cap D = \emptyset$ which could be possible also for $D \ne \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

$K_{\alpha_0}$ (pick any $\alpha_0$, the index set $A$ is irrelevant) is compact.

Then $L_\alpha:=K_\alpha \cap K_{\alpha_0}$, for $\alpha \in A$ are all closed subsets of $K_{\alpha_0}$ (by Hausdorffness all compact sets are closed and so intersecting them with $K_{\alpha_0}$ gives us closed subsets of $K_{\alpha_0}$ again. If one of these sets is empty, say $L_\alpha$ is, we are done because we can take $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha$ as the finite subset of the index set we have to find.
So we can assume they're all non-empty, but still $$\bigcap_{\alpha \in A} L_\alpha = \bigcap_{\alpha \in A} K_\alpha = \emptyset$$

and so the (open in $K_{\alpha_0}$) sets $U_\alpha = K_{\alpha_0} \setminus L_\alpha$ ( where $\alpha \in A$) form an open cover of $K_{\alpha_0}$: if not, some point would not be covered by any $U_\alpha$ and this point would thus be in all sets $K_{\alpha_0}\setminus U_\alpha = L_\alpha$ contrary to this intersection being empty.

As $K_{\alpha_0}$ is compact, finitely many $\alpha_1, \ldots \alpha_n$ exist such that $U_{\alpha_i}, i=1, \ldots n$ cover $K_{\alpha_0}$ and then it's equally clear that $K_{\alpha_0},K_{\alpha_1}, \ldots, K_{\alpha_n}$ have empty intersection and we are done: suppose $p$ would be in this intersection, then we'd have a point in $K_{\alpha_0}$ that is also in none of the $U_{\alpha_i}, i=1, \ldots n$, while we know this to be a finite cover of $K_{\alpha_0}$.

Comment: Could you explain the last part: that is also in none of the $_{_}$? where does it come from?

Comment: @Isa because $p$ is by assumption in all $K_{\alpha_i}, i=1, \ldots n$ and so $p \notin U_{\alpha_i}$ for those $i$ (the $U_{\alpha_i}$ are the complements of the $K_{\alpha_i}$, remember?)

Comment: I don't see how you got the contradiction, why you said that $U_{\alpha_i}$ are the complements of $K_{\alpha_i}$?. Are you using $U_\alpha = K_{\alpha_0} \setminus L_\alpha$ which is equivalent to $U_\alpha^c=(K_{\alpha_0}^c\cup K_\alpha)$ somehow?

Comment: @Isa Don't forget that $p \in K_{\alpha_0}$ as well (we assumed it was). So if $p \in K_{\alpha}$ it is not in $U_\alpha$ for any $\alpha$ too.